# Ping to local machine going through the gateway

Tags: networking, ip

I have a local machine (printer) on a network with a /29 class of service and when I ping the private address (10.1.10.97) locally I get a response like:

> From x.x.x.x (gateway address) Redirect Host (New nexthop: 10.1.10.97)
>   64 bytes from 10.1.10.97: icmp_seq ....

So, the printer is answering to the local address through the gateway. Why is it going through the gateway? Shouldn't I be getting a response directly from the local machine? Also, if I ping the printer's regular IPv4 address, I get host unreachable.

Is that because the printer does not know its own IPv4 address, so it is ignoring packets sent to that address or is there a deeper problem?

Comment: Can you provide the full ip address and subnet mask for the printer and for the host that you're pinging the printer from?

Comment: Please show a routing table on the PC and a route tracing output.

Comment: What is the gateway address? You posted x.x.x.x instead of the actual address.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did not post my gateway address for privacy reasons. How would my particular IP address make any difference to the answer?

Comment: At the moment it's impossible to even understand the problem without the actual IP addresses, not only of your gateway, but most likely of your local system from which you're pinging. It's also a little difficult to understand what "privacy" has to do with RFC1918 addresses anyway.

Comment: You are pinging from one local machine to another, right? We need the local IP addresses of both machines along with any network masks or subnet lengths used on your local network.